# Does Ionic/Angular Have an Integrated Session/Token System?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been a part of Ionic and developing apps with their platform for several years now. Have I missed a feature set somewhere which automatically handles logins, storing of bearer/JSON tokens, and the handling of 401 unauthorized service calls?

- I realize I personally can use Ionic-Storage for storing the bearer
  token.
- I realize I personally can use Ionic's Auth Guards for
  protecting routes when a user isn't logged in.
- I realize I personally
  can use some handling in http to know what to do with the 401 errors,
  etc. when a call to a service comes back unauthorized.

It just seems with as many things as Ionic has handled to make app development a bit more streamlined, this is something that should be a "package" of some sort.

Am I doing this correctly using all of these individual ways of managing user sessions and service calls, or is there another more complete part of Ionic's framework I'm just not aware of or a cordova package which handles all of it?